# Who provides implementation(s) of the PackageManager class?

Tags: android, class

I am looking at source code for the `PackageManager` class and it is abstract as well as all the methods. Are manufacturers supposed to write a real implementation for it, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PackageManager` is abstract and a concrete implementation needs to be provided in order to invoke instance methods. An implementation of this class can be found as a package private static class of `ApplicationContext` which itself is available in `ContextImpl`. (For source code [see here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java)). Note that this implementation of PackageManager is final and so cannot be overriden.

There is also a [MockPackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockPackageManager.html) implementation that might interest you.

Answer (score 9):

The real implementation for the PackageManager is PackageManagerService located at frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/

You can find the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#PackageManagerService.checkSignatures%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) in the GrepCode.

Comment: I tried to look for PackageManagerService here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/java/com/android/server, but it is not here.

Answer (score 6):

It is [`ApplicationPackageManager`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/ApplicationPackageManager.java#ApplicationPackageManager), and it is created in [`ContextImpl.getPackageManager()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#216).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling upon this old question, go to the source (`android.googlesource.com`)  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java, grepcode is long gone.