# Android source code navigation

Tags: android

I recently downloaded the source code for Android. There are many folders starting from the root level and I was wondering if there is any resource on the web containing just an overview of the contents of different folders and where common libraries/framework classes reside.

Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/search.html ?

Answer (score 4):

The Android project is made by a bunch of smaller projects, all of them downloaded when you clone the Android repo (with repo init ...). I don't know if there's such a resource explaining what each project is and I wouldn't expect there is one.

Android framework classes are in their majority under frameworks/base/ directory, while apps like Settings, Browser and others can be found under packages/apps/. A really good way to navigate the sources is to use find + grep if you're under Linux. Another approach that goes SO independent is using Eclipse to navigate the sources. For this last approach, you can find the details here: http://blog.michael-forster.de/2008/12/view-android-source-code-in-eclipse.html

Note that classes in the framework that are not visible for application developers are not that well documented, so if you're planning on customizing Android be prepared to read a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're after the [javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)?

Comment: For example, I wanted to look at source code for Package Manager, so even after looking at online documentation, I could not find where the file was located in the source code hierarchy, so I had to search and find from another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052659/packagemanager-class . I just was looking for some resource that would reduce time in search.

Comment: Oh right, well if you just want to _find_ classes, you could just use your IDE (Ctrl-Shift-T in Eclipse), assuming you've open the source in an IDE that is.